# How to add SharePoint 2013 list as Project Server 2013 Data Connection in Dashboard designer

Tags: 2013, list, project-server, dashboard-designer-2013

When I pick SharePoint list as Data connection, I cannot see that connection for new report.
Anybody else had this issue or know the solution of this problem?

Comment: Which type of list are you using?

Comment: Kindly look into this...http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/products/Pages/ms-project-server-sharepoint-integration.aspx

Comment: I am using custom list, but Any type of list I would be ok with.

Comment: Have you tried given link in above comment?

Comment: I read it, but that is not what I need. As written above, I need to put SharePoint list as data source.